# google app engine 500 Unknown error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, http-status-code-500

While calling endpoint API, sometimes we are getting 500 Unknown error from server, but most of the time API works fine. And also in case of 500 Unknown error, we are unable to see any logs in google console logs.
API response takes 2 sec approx. We are using App engine Java deployment.

Can anyone help me find the root cause of this problem?

Following is the chrome console error 
/conge-portal/#!/dashboard/myage:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://a-master-server.appspot.com/_ah/api/ageEndPoint/v1/aghie…5648/674390454714943921958166322392772?showTarget=true&month=May&year=2017. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: Start by using basic debugging stps, by emitting log events in major entry points in your code. It's not clear when you say "unable to see any google console logs" what you mean? The request must be in the request log.

Comment: Google console logs at console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=name do not show any entry in this case.

Comment: Well that error tells you a lot.  It suggests its not even hit your own code.

Comment: @Mehar same is happening to me, and the log console in Google Cloud is not showing the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue stopped after migrating to endpoint framework 2.0

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like browser rejected a preflight [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) OPTIONS request because "http://localhost" is not listed as the the allowed origins.

Are you using App Engine standard or App Engine Flex environment? CORS handling are different on these two platforms.

Comment: I am using App Engine standard